# how to integrate PMD plugin on Spring tool suite 3.8?

Tags: plugins, pmd

I need to  enable PMD plugin for STS 3.8 version. Have tried with url http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/ and it seems like this url is getting blocked. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: What is the error you see when you visit the URL?

Comment: That url has been deprecated, the new one is http://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/  as stated [on the official site](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/usage/integrations.html#Eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the below alternate url able to install PMD

http://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse Marketplace.

Click `Help` > `Eclipse Marketplace...` and find by keyword "PMD". After PMD plugin is shown, then click "Install" button.